# jQuery scrolling force won't scroll more than 450px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

```
//Scroll Status abfragen}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();




$("#vor").click(function() {

    if(wScroll < 450) { 
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 450
    }, 2000);
    }

    if(wScroll < 1900 & wScroll > 450 ) { 
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 1900
    }, 2000);
    }

 });

    });//wScroll
```

what happens when I click on the icon #vor is that it will scroll to 450 but I can't scroll past 450px after the animation ended. not by hand/mouse and not by click Im a newbie but I've tried to fix this for so long and can't find a way... Thanks for your help!

EDIT
btw. the following code is:

```
$("#pfeil").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 450 }, 2000);
});
```

and it works perfectly fine. The problem has to be in the wSroll function....

Comment: Im so new to all of this that I don't have any accounts where I could upload this right now :/ what else would you need? maybe I can tell you.. the website is pretts big...

Comment: i dont think its this function causing this issue i would of just liked to see this problem with my own eyes and debug it through the browser.. have you tried to put a breakpoint and step through the code?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what a breakpoint and step is?!

Comment: thanks for your patience! Even though I got no clue haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's calling your assignment hundreds of times because you're assigning the click event with every scroll, so they just keep adding up. It isn't locking your scroll, so much as not done with all the functions it has to run.

Change it to the following: 3 edits, the removal of var, the addition of the closing }); and the removal of the last });

```
//Scroll Status abfragen}
$(window).scroll(function() {
  wScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); //Get rid of var, so it can be used by functions outside of this function.

}); // That's all the work we need to do.






$("#vor").click(function() {
  console.log('Called');
  if (wScroll < 450) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 450
    }, 2000);

  }

  if (wScroll < 1900 & wScroll > 450) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 1900
    }, 2000);
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/dke33uyk/3/